# Cant fetch contacts from iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, abaddressbook

I have tried to fetch all the emails saved in contacts,I am able to fetch th eemails in ipod,But when i test on iphone it shows the arrays are null.But there are contacts in my iphone

why this happens ?

```
 -(IBAction)contactfriends:(id)sender
  {
   ABAddressBookRef _addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreate();
   NSArray* allPeople = (__bridge NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(_addressBookRef);

   NSMutableDictionary  *contactsInformation = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:[allPeople count]];
   NSMutableArray *propertyList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"property lsit %@",propertyList);   // I am getting this null
    NSLog(@"all people %@",allPeople);        // I am getting this null


   for (id record in allPeople)
   {
     CFTypeRef emailProp = ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge ABRecordRef)record, kABPersonEmailProperty);
    NSString *email = [((__bridge NSArray *)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(emailProp)) objectAtIndex:0 ];
    if (!email) {
        email = @"";
    }
     [propertyList addObject:email];

}

NSLog(@"property lsit %@",propertyList);      // I am getting this null
```

}

Comment: Check whether your app have permission for accessing the contact list

Comment: How to check that... ??

Comment: Please go to settings app and there will be a tab called `Privacy` on that tab select `Contacts` and check it is on for your app or not

Comment: no..there is no my app,
How to access the permission..plz help me bro

Comment: Means not listed your App or switch is off ?

Comment: When I use some other apps..it asks permission before accessing contacts,in mine it is not there

But without that its working fine on iPod

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    NSArray *people = (NSArray*)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
    for(id person in people){
            ABMultiValueRef multiemail = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
            for (CFIndex j=0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(multiemail); j++) {
                    NSString* email = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiemail, j);
                    [arrAllEmail addObject:email];
                    NSLog(@"%@",email);
                    [email release];
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using iOS6 then you need to check the permission for accessing accounts programmatically.

you could check the permission in your code like this

```
// Request authorization to Address Book
  ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);

  if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBookRef, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
      // First time access has been granted, add the contact
       // add your contacts or get emails
    });
  }
  else if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
    // The user has previously given access, add the contact
    // add your contacts or get emails
  }
  else {
    // The user has previously denied access
     UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"permission denied " delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alert show];
  }
```